# Как 'считать' дату получаемую через the_date() в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Получаю дату поста через `the_date()`, чтобы не делать дополнительных манипуляций, сразу получаю дату в нужном формате `the_date('Y-m-d')`:

```
echo the_date('Y-m-d'); // 2018-01-13
```

**Пытаюсь добавить день в полученной дате:**

```
$date = new DateTime(the_date('Y-m-d'));
$date->modify('+1 day');

echo the_date('Y-m-d') . ', и новая дата: ' . $date->format('Y-m-d');
// 2018-01-13, и новая дата: 2018-01-17
// 2018-01-11, и новая дата: 2018-01-17
// 2018-01-09, и новая дата: 2018-01-17
```

Дата не подсчитана, такое ощущение, что полученные данные через the_date('Y-m-d') не числа, либо скрипт не понимает, что это дата...

**На всякий, пробую подсчитать тестовую дату:**

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->modify('+1 day');

echo '2000-01-01 . ', и новая дата: ' . $date->format('Y-m-d');
// 2000-01-01, и новая дата: 2000-01-02
```

Подсчет успешен, дни, месяцы и годы добавляются штатно...

Так в чем проблема `the_date('Y-m-d')`, как его 'готовить'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция `the_date()` **выводит** дату поста (по сути, делает `echo get_the_date();`). Для получения даты и передачи её в качестве параметра используйте функцию `get_the_date()`:

```
$date = new DateTime(get_the_date('Y-m-d'));
$date->modify('+1 day');

echo get_the_date('Y-m-d') . ', и новая дата: ' . $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**UPD:** Кстати, не нужно использовать `echo` для вывода `the_date()`, так как `echo the_date();` эквивалентно `echo echo get_the_date();`.

Comment: Благодарю! Очень помогли!